# Colo alocar uma memória baseado no tamanho do que o usuário digitou

Tags: c, memória, alocação

Como eu posso fazer com que logo após o usuário digitar uma *string* o programa conte o número 'x' de caracteres desta e aloque X bytes para ela?

Não estou conseguindo fazê-lo, tentei por exemplo fazer com que após o usuário digitar a string, isso:

```
ponteiro = (char *) malloc (strlen(string));
```

No código acima, o usuário dando uma entrada, por exemplo, do tipo: ABCDEF, faria com que a strlen contasse 6 caracteres, assim alocando para a string 6 bytes.

Mas dá errado, já que a alocação de memória estaria acontecendo depois, assim antes da string ser 'pega' não existiria bytes alocados para armazená-la.
Alguém sabe de que maneira resolvo isso?

Comment: Como o usuário está digitando? Coloque seu código. Talvez seu problema esteja em outro lugar. Mas já posso adiantar que você terá que alocar antes de receber a informação.

Comment: bigdown, no momento o código está assim: http://codepad.org/oqBIJKVG, mas o que quero é que o programa não pergunte a quantidade de bytes que o usuário vai usar, mas que o programa após o usuário digitar a string, use a strlen e calcule o número de caracteres digitados e aloque-os. Entendeu?

Comment: @LeviIvanovsk Por esses e outros motivos (orientação de objetos, por exemplo) que eu escolhi o C++. E ele dá muitos resultados melhores no Google. Dá uma olhada!

Comment: @LeviIvanovsk Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: bota malloc(sizeof(string)), isso retorna o tamanho ocupado na memória pela variavel string

Answer (score 3):

Não existe muitas opções. Basicamente ou você aloca antes uma quantidade suficiente para o que precisa ou pergunta quanto quer alocar.

A segunda opção realmente é terrível. Do ponto de vista de usabilidade não faz o menor sentido.

A primeira opção tem a desvantagem de possivelmente alocar mais memória do que o realmente necessário. Mas quem se importa. Isso não é um problema mais em nenhum tipo de dispositivo a não ser que queira entrar com texto realmente muito longo, mas você não faria isto de forma simples de qualquer forma, em um texto longo teria um estrutura de dados para gerenciar isto.

Alguém pode pensar que também há a desvantagem de impor um limite máximo. Mas isto é uma vantagem. Deixar um usuário qual é o limite máximo de texto a digitar é a última coisa que o programa deveria fazer. Novamente, se precisa de algo mais complexo, precisará de um programa mais complexo.

Então a solução é fazer isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char *ponteiro = malloc(100); //um caractere será ocupado pelo terminador \0
    printf("String: ");
    scanf("%99s", ponteiro); //permite digitar um caractere a menos que o alocado 
    free(ponteiro);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0qfnqK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yxaeshdq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/MallocFree.c).

Agora apareceram respostas que mostram algoritmos criativos mas que provavelmente serão *overkill*. Minha solução desperdiça memória, as outras apresentadas desperdiçam tempo de alocação e no comentário apareceu uma que desperdiça ou dois mas em quantidades moderadas.

Percebeu que não há almoço grátis? Você tem que decidir o que pretende desperdiçar. Em um exemplo simples qualquer pode ser desperdiçada sem problemas. Eu usaria a [navalha de Occam](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navalha_de_Occam) e ficaria com a mais simples. Se eu preferisse a mais complicada eu teria postada ela.

Eu poderia usar uma versão otimizada e melhor tratada em problemas mais complexos onde eu realmente estivesse com problemas de memória e não soubesse o tamanho do que preciso em entrada de dados. Eu não tenho nenhum desses problemas nunca então nunca me preocupei com isso. Acho que você também não deveria.

Comment: "Leibniz (1646-1716), Kant (1724-1804), Karl Menger (século XX) também discordaram da navalha de Occam.

Leibniz afirmou que "a variedade de seres não pode ser diminuída".

Menger formulou a lei contra a avareza, segundo a qual "as entidades não podem ser reduzidas até ao ponto da inadequação", e "é inútil fazer com pouco o que requer mais"...

Obviamente nenhuma destas afirmações contraria realmente o sentido da Navalha de Occam, mas servem antes como alerta contra o excesso de zelo na aplicação do princípio. Deve-se eliminar o supérfluo, mas apenas isso." *hehehe*.

Answer (score 3):

Há uma maneira de fazer o que você quer, mas o desempenho do código é questionável dependendo da situação.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ALLOCATION_STEP 5

int main(void)
{
    int mem_left = ALLOCATION_STEP;
    int mem_size = mem_left + 1;
    int length = 0;
    int realloc_cnt = 0;
    char *buff = (char *)malloc(mem_left);
    char c = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if(mem_left == 0) { // precisamos de mais memoria
            char *tmp = (char *)realloc(buff,mem_size + ALLOCATION_STEP);
            if(tmp == NULL) {
                printf("Falha na aquisicao de memoria!\n");
                free(buff);
                return -1;
            }
            buff = tmp;
            mem_left = ALLOCATION_STEP;
            mem_size += mem_left;
            ++realloc_cnt;
        }
        buff[length++] = c;
        --mem_left;
    }

    buff[length] = '\0'; // fecha a string

    printf("Tamanho: %d\n",length);
    printf("Memoria: %d\n",mem_size);
    printf("Padding: %d\n",mem_size - (length+1));
    printf("Realocacoes: %d\n",realloc_cnt);
    printf("String: %s\n",buff);

    free(buff);
    buff = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

O código acima aloca uma quantidade inicial de memória dada pelo valor de `ALLOCATION_STEP`, então ele começa a ler a stream de entrada até encontrar uma quebra de linha `\n`, ao longo do processo ele vai copiando os caracteres da stream para a variável `buff`, se a quantidade de memória restante indicada por `mem_left` chegar a `0` ele realoca mais `ALLOCATION_STEP` bytes de memória para continuar o processo até o fim ou até que um erro de alocação ocorra.

O problema é: Um `ALLOCATION_STEP` muito baixo pode fazer com que muitas realocações aconteçam tornando o desempenho do código questionável, também há o uso abusivo da função `realloc` que pode trazer problemas.

Comment: Em vez de incrementar o tamanho do buffer de 5 em 5, multiplique o tamanho do buffer por uma constante em cada passo (por exemplo, dobre o tamanho do buffer a cada alocação). Assim a performance amortizada fica linear ao invés de quadrática.

Comment: @hugomg Sim, é uma alternativa válida, meu código é apenas uma base de como fazer o que o OP quer, por isso coloquei essa quantidade em um `#define` para simbolizar que ela pode ser aumentada para se adequar a situação e melhorar o desempenho ou também mudar a quantidade como o buffer cresce.

Comment: Eu acho a resposta válida e acho que de quanto em quanto só importa se for pensar em fazer o certo. Se é para fazer "errado", que seja de 1 em 1 :) claro que de 5 em 5 fica um pouco melhor, dependendo do caso 10 em 10 ou 50 em 50. Melhor ainda se for progressivo geometricamente. Mas aí chegamos a conclusão que o certo mesmo é estabelecer um tamanho máximo que todo *input* deveria ter de qualquer forma e alocar ele. Resolve tudo.

Comment: Sim @bigown, comentei isso na outra resposta, sua resposta é a mais sensata por indiciar trabalhar com tamanhos fixos, postei esse código para expandir as opções do OP, e expliquei que deve-se manter um balanço entre a quantidade de realocações e o tamanho delas de acordo com sua necessidade, evitando perca de desempenho ou sobra de memória.

Comment: @Cahe: não era uma questão de ser configurável via define. Mudar o passo da sua progressão aritmética vai melhorar o tempo por um fator constante enquanto usar uma progressão geométrica resulta em uma complexidade assintótica melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Simples: da mesma maneira que o C++ faz com a [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/132947/). Deixa o buffer de input, lê de *chunk em chunk* e aloca mais memória conforme preciso.

Usa o [seguinte código](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164000/how-to-dynamically-allocate-memory-space-for-a-string-and-get-that-string-from-u):

```
char *getln()
{
    char *linha = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
    size_t tamanho = 0, index = 0;
    int ch = EOF;

    while (ch) {
        ch = getc(stdin);

        /* Checamos se devemos parar. */
        if (ch == EOF || ch == '\n')
            ch = 0;

        /* Checamos se devemos expandir. */
        if (tamanho <= index) {
            tamanho += CHUNK;
            tmp = realloc(linha, tamanho);
            if (!tmp) {
                free(linha);
                linha = NULL;
                break;
            }
             linha = tmp;
        }

        /* Finalmente adicionamos o caractere */
        linha[index++] = ch;
    }

    return linha;
}
```

Lembrando que CHUNK é um valor cabível a você. A maneira sem falhas é `#define CHUNK
 1`. O método pode alterar os resultados de tempo (*input* **muito** mais demorado).

Comment: @Rinzler Se não fosse uma boa prática, o C++ não o teria implementado no STL!

Comment: @Rinzler não é com orientação de objetos que se faz uma função relacionada com cadeia de caracteres. Eu programo em C++, eu fiz a pergunta relacionada (veja o *nickname*: iQChange) e perguntei pois estava implementando uma *string* nas minhas bibliotecas pessoais. Pense nas relações de C e C++ e você encontrará a "pequena" referência para uma linguagem procedural e orientada a objetos. (As duas usam o mesmo sistema lógico, as duas usam assembly, as duas tem o mesmo tipo de variáveis padrão, as duas... )

Comment: @LucasHenrique você tem uma fonte de onde especificamente isto é usado na STL? Este código apresentado certamente não faz parte da STL.

Comment: @bigown Tenho a citação da STL no link para o site cplusplus.com (link em std::string). É interessante como usam a orientação de objetos para fazer o mesmo **de uma maneira que pode ser implementada em C**.

Comment: @Rinzler tenho plena consciência dos motivos de criação do C++ sobre o C, seu "pai", e isso tento dizer a ti. Não conhecia o Simula; interessante.

Comment: A resposta mais sensata é a do @bigown que é trabalhar com tamanhos fixos, mesmo assim postei esse mesmo código 5 horas atrás, já expliquei e debati com o @hugomg os problemas do mesmo e como ele pode ser adaptado para resolver a pergunta, aliás definir `CHUNK` para para `1` é uma péssima ideia.

Comment: @Cahe O engraçado é que outras linguagens não tem esse problema e se adaptaram. Como? Ah, e o chunk = 1 eu só coloquei porque não prestei muita atenção no código e fiquei com medo de que se chunk fosse != sizeof(char) o programa desse pau por ter lixo na variável (haja preguiça!).

Comment: @LucasHenrique não achei nenhum *link* naquele fórum, nenhuma referência à palavra STL ou qualquer informação que indicasse isto que você está afirmando. O assunto lá é completamente diferente do que está sendo tratado aqui. Lá fala de manipulação de *string* e o algoritmo é extramente complexo, aqui é sobre entrada de dados. Pode não parecer mas o contexto onde está sendo utilizado tem muita importância para determinar o que usar. Eu acho que tem muita "viagem na maionese" nessa conversa.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/fq3ernjqx/ do meu computador. Vamos explicar o que quero dizer de maneira final e sucinta (anda logo!). O que é capturado é armazenado em um buffer e tem seu tamanho alterado dinamicamente a cada tecla (suponho). A std::string mostra a maneira que tamanho é alterado, e o meu código faz analogia à mesma.